# Is Pro*C/C++ communication secured?

Tags: security, oracle-pro-c

I need to know if `Pro*C/C++` (Oracle database connectivity for C/C++) communication is secured. Is it TCP/IP with plaintext? maybe some encryption (shared key?). Secured Tunnel of some sort?

Comment: Are you asking about the proc file system in Linux and Solaris (as in /proc)? it's not clear what you mean

Comment: No, I'm talking about: Pro*C (also known as Pro*C/C++) is an embedded SQL programming language used by Oracle Database and Sybase SQL Server database management systems. (copied from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro*C)

I tagged it correctly

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if you want an encrypted channel between your Pro*C client and the Oracle database server you'll need to use Oracle Advanced Security.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14268/asointro.htm

In the end it is really less to do with Pro*C as it is the SQLNET configuration that is used, since the right SQLNET setup could encrypt the data from SQL*PLUS or anything else that uses it.